# How does high dimensional data residing in low dimensional manifold have high variance?

Tags: machine-learning, bias-variance-tradeoff, manifold-learning

I was pondering over the fact that for a very high dimensional data, if it lies in a low dimesional manifold, then in the bias variance decomposition for it, the variance will be high and bias will be low. Is there any intuitive explanation or mathematical references for this? I am assuming the data is finite here (infact less data).

Comment: bias/variance decomposition of what?

Comment: @user20160 Although I had general loss function in mind but it would be fine for squared error loss too.